# ASP.NET MVC 3 Remote validation stopped working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using the client side validation for my views, and have just created a ViewModel which contains an organisation object and an address object.

I used to have a ViewModel that just mapped to the domain entity. On my domain entity I had the following:

```
[NotMapped]
    [Remote("ValidOrganisation", "Manage", "Organisations", ErrorMessage = "That organisation doesn't exist")]
    public string Organisation { get; set; }
```

However, I have now created a ViewModel for the view that contains the following:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public AddressModel Address { get; set; }
}
```

The person object contains the Organisation property.

In my view, I have the following:

```
<div>
            <label for="Organisation">Organisation</label>
            <div class="input large">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Person.Organisation)
                <span class="help-block">Type the first letter of the organisation to search</span>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Person.Organisation)
                @Html.Hidden("OrganisationID")
            </div>
        </div>
```

The only thing that changed was:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Organisation)
```

to:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Person.Organisation)
```

My remote validation code is:

```
public JsonResult ValidOrganisation(string organisation)
    {
        var exists = orgs.SelectAll().Where(o => o.Name.ToLower() == organisation.ToLower()).Count() > 0;

        return Json(exists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The problem is that NULL is now always being passed in, which is always returning false.

Is this something to do with the Organisation property now changing to be Person.Organisation?

Answer (score 1):

1] Open your view Page Source and see what is Id renderd for the

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Person.Organisation)
```

2] and  rename **organisation** in method to accept same ID I am expecting it to be **Person_Organisation**

```
public JsonResult ValidOrganisation(string organisation)
```

use below

```
public JsonResult ValidOrganisation(string Person_Organisation)
```

Comment: I've tried that, and the Person_Organisation is still always NULL. The ID is Person_Organisation and the name is Person.Organisation when a inspect element on the textbox.

Comment: use FireBug and let me know what URL and values has been sent to server?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I've managed to get around it by re-factoring the application a little. Although I still don't know why it refused to work using the method you specified above.